# Lua script is throwing "not enough memory" error

Tags: c, lua

In our project we are loading Lua as a dll in a Windows service (32 bit process on X64 Windows servers) and running scripts in parallel on different threads. It all works fine most of the times however, in cases where the script is doing memory intensive task (such as loading a large file and iterating through it while doing other processing) the script throws "not enough memory" error.
As per my understanding of the Windows OS's memory model, if the "not enough memory" error is being thrown it is because the process has crossed its memory quota (2 GB or if large memory aware linker option is set then 4GB) as there is no thread specific memory quota in Windows. But there are few points that I am not able to understand:

1. If there are multiple threads running Lua scripts and all are sharing the same address space of the process then why the "not enough memory" coming only on the thread which is doing heavy memory operation, it could come on any other script also, but it doesn't happen in practice?
2. Could this issue be related to lua Stack that is used to interact with c code?
3. Is there any internal memory limit that lua maintains (I couldn't find any reference of this btw).

Few points about our env:

1. It is a legacy product and uses Lua 5.1
2. There is no custom allocation function so the code use realloc for memory allocation

Any pointer in the direction why this could happen would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The situation is pretty simple: the script needs more memory.  To solve the problem, you have to carefully rewrite your code, choose more memory-efficient algorithms for processing large data.

Comment: Does the script have a limit over memory? Because other threads in the same process continue to run without any error.

Comment: There are no internal limits to memory allocation in Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else hits this : there is no memory limit in lua itself, the issue was happening because the process's address space was getting filled up completely because we were loading huge maps in memory. We fixed it by moving in memory data to disc (local db).